# measuring the I-V Curve for the n-channel mosfet bs170

Tags: transistors, raspberry-pi, nmos

I've done with the Pi and the Waveshare A/D D/A High Precision a simple curve tracer. So far, it works perfectly for a resistor and a diode. However, I'm trying right know with the n-channel MOSFET (BS170), and the results are not that I expected and I don't know exactly why. I would appreciate if someone could explain to me why I got these results. For this, it was applied first a fixed voltage to the DAC0, while it was incrementing the DAC1 from 0 to 5 V, by steps of 0,5V. When the process finished, it was incremented the DAC0 voltage by 1 V, and it was repeated the process with the DAC1 until the tension generated in both DACs is equal to 5.0 V. The characterization circuit is presented below as well as the obtained curves.

[image: This is the characterization circuit]

Id vs Vds
[image: Id vs Vds]

Id vs Vgs
[image: Id vs Vgs]

Id is calculated as Id=(vcc-vds)/R

Comment: Can you explain what you think are wrong with these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically curve traces for MOSFETs are measured with Vg at set of useful, fixed values between the Gate-Source Threshold Voltage, Vgs(th), and Gate Source Voltage, Vgs. The value of Vds is then swept between 0 and some useful value at or below about 70% of the Drain-Source breakdown Voltage, Vdss(br).

Note that it is also not uncommon to pulse the gate and use values up to Vgsm. Most good component data sheets give a reference schematic of the test fixture. Vishay Siliconix has a very thorough application note, [Measuring Power MOSFET Characteristics](http://www.vishay.com/docs/90715/an957.pdf), that is worth a look to better understand how such things are tested.